# How can I convert csv to pickle?

Tags: dataframe, csv, google-colaboratory, pickle

I have some csv files which take a bit long to load as dataframe into my workspace. Is there a fast and easy tool to convert them to pickle to load faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you load the data using Pandas,
Use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df.to_pickle('/Drive Path/df.pkl')    #to save the dataframe, df to 123.pkl
df1 = pd.read_pickle('/Drive Path/df.pkl') #to load 123.pkl back to the dataframe df
```